# Crack with Hashcat using hash and salt

Tags: salt, hashcat

I am new to Hashcat and I am trying to crack a password/salt hash.  Everything I have tried comes back as "no hash-mode matches..."  Any assistance on the correct hashcat command line would be appreciated.

```
salt:b9v62crdfsq6nz8btkf2e4
hash:e1387874f8a0d5180d455f53f3d93eff1ce7e89f6863d1c3b7c9ee441324eb23688011262b923fda05b9def0018dfacee4ab47658310e83554199a999ebf895c
```

Comment: This looks like a SHA2-512. You need to know at least how the salt is concatenated with the input, and how many iterations it have.

Comment: Whenever asking for help with a command, please provide the full command you used and the full output, and not just your summaries. Also, have you looked at the hashcat documentation for how to specify the hash and how to provide the salt?

Answer (score 3):

Your hash looks, as already mentioned, like a sha-512 hash.

Since you also have a salt given, according to [hashcat example hashes](https://hashcat.net/wiki/doku.php?id=example_hashes), you need to specify hash mode 1710 `-m 1710`, which is `sha512($pass.$salt)`, and provide the hash in the pattern `<hash>:<salt>` or as presented in the example hashes:

```
e5c3ede3e49fb86592fb03f471c35ba13e8d89b8ab65142c9a8fdafb635fa2223c24e5558fd9313e8995019dcbec1fb584146b7bb12685c7765fc8c0d51379fd:6352283260
```